# Alibaba ACP question about CDN(NEED EXPLAIN)

Tags: alibaba-cloud

Many combination samples of Alibaba Cloud CDN with other cloud products and business scenarios are provided for reference on the Alibaba Cloud official website.
Alibaba Cloud CDN is NOT a suitable option for the following _________ scenarios.

A. BBS forums with less than 100 page views daily.

B. Purely static sites with more than 100,000 page views daily on Alibaba Cloud
virtual host.

C. Images, HTML, CSS and JS files on a medium-sized e-commerce website.

D. News portal websites with more than 30 million page views daily and users all around the country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option A, (BBS forums with less than 100 page views daily) is the correct answer.

Purpose of the CDN service is to improve the performance of the site loading by serving the contents from the near by Point of Presence. The number of visitors are less than 100, so it does justify adding CDN services.